# Wordpress too many redirect custom function

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I tried to set custom redirects for specified files, like if url contains wp-login.php then redirect to the home url, the first statement is working and redirect the page to the home url but in the else i got this error:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Here is my code in **functions.php**

```
function secure_redirect(){

$page_viewed = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if($page_viewed != "wp-login.php?secure_login")
{
   if(strpos($page_viewed, "wp-login.php") !== false)
   {
       wp_redirect(get_site_url());
   }
}
else
{
   wp_redirect(get_site_url()."/".$page_viewed);
}

}

add_action('init','secure_redirect');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want specific to redirect then why you have put redirection code in else part also? Skip the else part. Write redirection code only on if part

```
function secure_redirect(){

$page_viewed = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if($page_viewed != "wp-login.php?secure_login")
{
   if(strpos($page_viewed, "wp-login.php") !== false)
   {
       wp_redirect(get_site_url());
   }
}

}

add_action('init','secure_redirect');
```